# 'field' is of type unknown

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to deploy my code but when running the build, on TS I am getting a 'object' is of type unknown error and I'm trying to figure out how to solve it on my situation.

```
export default function Home() {
  async function sendEmail(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = {};
    Array.from(e.currentTarget.elements).forEach(field => {
      if ( !field.name ) return;
      formData[field.name] = field.value;
    });

    await fetch('/api/email', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    });
    document.getElementById('emailform').onreset();
  }
  
  return (
    <form className={styles.submitformcont}  method="post" onSubmit={sendEmail} id='emailform'>
                  <label className={styles.fullnamelbl} htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                  <br/>
                  <input className={styles.fullnamebtn} type="text" id="name" placeholder='Name'  name="name" />

                  <br/>
                  <br/>

                  <label className={styles.emaillbl} htmlFor="mail">E-mail:</label>
                  <br/>
                  <input className={styles.emailbtn}type="email" id="mail" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" required/>

                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <label className={styles.textlbl}htmlFor="msg">Message:</label>
                  <br/>
                  <textarea className={styles.textbtn} id="msg" name="Message"  placeholder="Message"></textarea>

                  <br/>

                  <button className={styles.submitbtn}> Submit </button>
    </form>
)}
```

'field' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046)

Comment: Your question needs some more information. What is `e`? Is this an event handler? What event is it handling? When I paste your code into an event handler function, I get [a lot of unrelated errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYewxgrgtgpgdgFwHQENjAKIDd4IDICWAzgvDAE4AUA5FCBETKAO5zUA0ABJTAJScBeAHycA3gChOUzgEFy5FAE8kAM3IgoPJJHm4AKinIBzGMhgAbGLERFeqkOQwowAC0oqCF4IJETp0ghVuTgBCDy8kOBRYTn5yUwhyOABuSX9OFQcoABEUBBQAbXDzYEjomABdQQzPEqQsFHMIGFT-AF9eVI7xcSA). Please create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`e.target.elements` contain the `button` element, you don't want to collect the value of the `button` element. So you should check the type of the `field`. Collect the value only if it's `HTMLInputElement` or `HTMLTextAreaElement`.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  async function sendEmail(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = {};
    Array.from(e.currentTarget.elements).forEach((field) => {
      if (
        field instanceof HTMLInputElement ||
        field instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement
      ) {
        if (!field.name) return;
        formData[field.name] = field.value;
      }
    });

    await fetch('/api/email', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });
    (document.getElementById('emailform') as HTMLFormElement).reset();
  }

  return (
    <form method="post" onSubmit={sendEmail} id="emailform">
      <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" />
      <label htmlFor="mail">E-mail:</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        id="mail"
        name="email"
        placeholder="Enter your Email"
        required
      />
      <label htmlFor="msg">Message:</label>
      <textarea id="msg" name="Message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <button> Submit </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hvapz4?file=App.tsx)